# Scipy minimize.optimize LBFGS vs PyTorch LBFGS

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, pytorch

I have written some code with `scipy.optimize.minimize` using the LBFGS algorithm. Now I want to implement the same with PyTorch.

SciPy:

```
res = minimize(calc_cost, x_0, args = const_data, method='L-BFGS-B', jac=calc_grad)
def calc_cost(x, const_data):
   # do some calculations with array "calculation" as result
   return np.sum(np.square(calculation)) #this returns a scalar!
def calc_grad(x, const_data):
   # do some calculations which result in array "calculation"
   return np.ravel(calculation) #in PyTorch this returns without ravel!
```

Now in PyTorch I am following [this example](https://gist.github.com/tuelwer/0b52817e9b6251d940fd8e2921ec5e20). However, I want to use my own gradient calculation. This results in the error `RuntimeError: Mismatch in shape: grad_output[0] has a shape of torch.Size([3, 200, 200]) and output[0] has a shape of torch.Size([]).` I understand that the shape/size of my gradient *should* be the same as the objective function (i.e. here a scalar), but this is not what I need (see above). How do I adapt the following code in a way that it does the same calculations as the SciPy version:

```
optimizer = optim.LBFGS([x_0], history_size=10, max_iter=10, line_search_fn="strong_wolfe")
h_lbfgs = []
for i in range(10):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    objective = calc_cost(x_0, const_data)
    objective.backward(gradient = calc_gradient(x_0, const_data))
    optimizer.step(lambda: calc_cost(x_0, const_data))
    h_lbfgs.append(objective.item())
```

I have had a look at the PyTorch docs already but don't quite understand how they apply here:

- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.LBFGS.html
- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#optimizer-step-closure

Comment: whoever just gave -1, could you please explain where my question doesn't fulfill the criteria listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was using the wrong "objective" function. What I am trying to optimize is the `x_0` array, therefore I had to alter my code as follows:

```
for i in range(10):
   optimizer.zero_grad()
   x_0.backward(gradient = calc_gradient(x_0, const_data))
   optimizer.step(lambda: calc_cost(x_0, const_data))
   h_lbfgs.append(objective.item())
```